# Why does Go panic() take interface{} instead of ...interface{} as argument?

Tags: go

I noticed `panic` takes `interface{}` as an argument, while `fmt.Print` and the likes take `...interface{}`. Wouldn't it be more convenient if `panic` took `...interface{}` as well?

Why did the Go authors define `panic` as `func panic(v interface{})` rather than `func panic(v ...interface{})` (like they did with `fmt`)?

Comment: To moderators incorrectly voting to close this question: this has nothing to do with "opinion based": this is a very important question asking for the origin of a fundamental language design issue. Read my answer: there is no opinion there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`panic` didn't take just one argument at first.
You can trace back the one argument implementation back to 30th March 2010:
[commit 01eaf78](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/01eaf780a8d09ce0b41526fa2701cfbba80f2b8b) gc: add `panic` and `recover` (still unimplemented in runtime)

> main semantic change is to enforce single argument to panic.

The spec is fixed in [commit 5bb29fb](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/5bb29fb1160ed9c727a2b83aa9cf7c082ac5de26), and [commit 00f9f0c](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/00f9f0c0560ce35b9d006eacbeeacf897d19a2bf) illustrates how panic could took before multiple arguments:

```
src/pkg/bufio/bufio.go

b, err := NewWriterSize(wr, defaultBufSize)
if err != nil {
    // cannot happen - defaultBufSize is valid size
    - panic("bufio: NewWriter: ", err.String())
    + panic(err)
}
```

---

That follows a [proposal from March 25th, 2010](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/golang$20single$20argument$20panic/golang-nuts/HOXNBQu5c-Q/Je0qo1hbxIsJ):

> We don't want to encourage the conflation of errors and exceptions that occur in languages such as Java.
>
> Instead, this proposal uses a slight change to the definition of defer and a couple of runtime functions to provide a clean mechanism for handling truly exceptional conditions.
>
> During panicking, if a deferred function invocation calls recover, recover returns the value passed to panic and stops the panicking.
> At any other time, or inside functions called by the deferred call, recover returns nil.
> After stopping the panicking, a deferred call can panic with a new argument, or the same one, to continue panicking.
> Alternately, the deferred call might edit the return values for its outer function, perhaps returning an error.

In those various scenario, dealing with one value to pass around seems easier than dealing with an variable number of arguments (especially when it comes to [implement `recover` in C](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/9b1507b05098b95639d6d4905534426193f75f15#diff-65826dc18b9f9dd9a72750dfc95f269eR986)).

Comment: Furthermore, if panic were variadic, as a convenience for something like `errors.New(fmt.Sprint(...args))` it would encourage use of panic, when in reality, use of panic as a control-flow mechanism is discouraged, and should rarely, if ever, cross package boundaries. When such panics do occur, they should be clearly documented in the package documentation for each function where they occur.

Answer (score 2):

Because the value you pass to `panic` is a value you want to panic with and can be retrieved using `recover`. Having multiple panic values doesn't really make sense.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    defer func() {
        if v := recover(); v != nil {
            fmt.Println(v.(int))
        }
    }()
    panic(3)
}
```

Example on using recover values:

> For a real-world example of panic and recover, see the json package
>   from the Go standard library. It decodes JSON-encoded data with a set
>   of recursive functions. When malformed JSON is encountered, the parser
>   calls panic to unwind the stack to the top-level function call, which
>   recovers from the panic and returns an appropriate error value (see
>   the 'error' and 'unmarshal' methods of the decodeState type in
>   decode.go).

Source: http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

Comment: But you're never supposed to use panic except for really exceptional situations, right? So if I need to handle an error, I just handle the `err`. If my program panics, I just want it to crash, or to print it to some log. If it took a vararg you could still just look at the first item in the slice, and your use-case would be covered, easily. Passing an error code and the struct that caused it seems like a good use of multiple arguments.

Comment: @FilipHaglund I updated the answer with an example how panic is used internally for json decoding.

Comment: Yes, I've read that. That's one use, but that isn't the general use for panic, or is it? Unwinding the stack would be done with `if err != nil` fairly quickly as well, right?